# Cloning a Windows 10 Hard Drive with dd

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, dd

I'm migrating a Windows 10 install from a SATA 3 SSD to an NVMe drive for a friend. The plan was to image the drive, give the original disk back to my friend so he can use it in the meantime, and once I received the NVMe drive, just write the image to it.

I imaged the original disk with:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/disk5 of=/Volumes/Data/old-drive.img
```

Then, when I got the new drive, I wrote the image to it with:

```
sudo dd if=/Volumes/Data/old-drive.img of=/dev/disk5
```

I had assumed that this, being a bit-by-bit image, would make the new disk bootable. However, when I plugged it in, it's not booting.

If I mount the disk on another box, I can see that it has all the files in it etc, so I think it's just the boot sector that got corrupted.

Is there a way to get the new disk booting without having to write the whole thing again? And, what's the correct way to use dd to end up with a bootable drive?

p.s. I used `dd` in a Mac.

Comment: Any preinstalled Windows 10 is in UEFI mode so the ESP (EFI System Partition) is the one that should have the boot flag for Windows to work. If however it was installed by the user then it could be anything and then, if Legacy/BIOS it requires the MBR with the Windows bootloader to boot. DD typically doesn't copy this, only partitions. Also it seems NVMe drives really prefer GPT/UEFI mode.

Comment: So, at the end of the day, a lot of effort and wasted time for no real gain. Although cloning can be done in most cases, almost always a fresh installation is preferable.

Comment: A fresh install would mean having to re-install all software, data, and settings the way they were before. Now that seems like a lot of effort and wasted time. Thanks for the lead re/ UEFI. I'll try looking into that as a solution before resorting to a reinstall.

Comment: Linux is a lot more forgiving in that regard. Linux drivers typically are kernel modules so support for a wide range of hardware is pretty much guaranteed even when "transplanting" from a PC to a very different one. Definitely not the same with Windows albeit there are way to recover, uninstall old drivers and install the new ones so Windows can work (+/-). However, if the hardware is generations apart and especially when the old is BIOS and the new UEFI then a fresh installation is highly recommended. Data backup should be a religion so the only time consuming tasks are drivers, software, etc

Comment: Thanks @ChanganAuto - I see. I thought that's something Windows 10 had improved on. I haven't been a regular Windows user since Win 7, but I see people on youtube move hard drives from system to system with seemingly no issues, so I thought they had fixed it. Sounds like they do that with systems that are more similar and/or with more work behind the scenes.